# Listen to any field changes under nested FormGroup using valueChanges

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to listen if any field changes or not using valueChanges by angular. Below is my code

```js
      this.advSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        noCountry: this.formBuilder.group({
          licenseOwnerName: [null, [Validators.maxLength(256)]],
          locationAddressLine1: [null, [Validators.maxLength(256)]],
          DBAName: [null, [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
          locationCity: [null, [Validators.maxLength(60)]],
          licenseNumber: [null, [Validators.maxLength(256)]],        
          issuingAuthorityName: [null, [Validators.maxLength(256)]],
        }),        
        locationState: [null],
        locationCountry: [null]
      });

      const lNumber = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.licenseNumber');
      const lCountry = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('locationCountry');
      const lState = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('locationState');
      const lAddress = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.locationAddressLine1');
      const lOwner = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.licenseOwnerName');
      const lCity = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.locationCity');
      const dName = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.DBAName');
      const iAuthority = <FormControl>this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry.issuingAuthorityName');
      
      this.subscription = this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue  => {
        if (lCountry.value == 287307 && lAddress.value == null  && lOwner.value == null  && lCity.value == null  && dName.value == null  && iAuthority.value == null  && lNumber.value == null ) {  
          lState.setValidators([Validators.required ]);
          console.log(selectedValue);
        }
        else {
          lState.setValidators(null);
        }  
        lState.updateValueAndValidity();  
      });
```

And I am trying to listen to it with

```js
       this.advSearchForm.get('noCountry').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue  => { ....
```

HTML

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="advSearchForm" class="search_main_form" >         
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">License Owner: </label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="licenseOwnerName" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseOwnerName" maxlength="256">                
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Location Address Line 1: </label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="locationAddressLine1" class="form-control" formControlName="locationAddressLine1" maxlength="256">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dba_name">DBA Name: </label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="DBAName" class="form-control" formControlName="DBAName" maxlength="255">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location_city">Location City: </label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="locationCity" class="form-control" formControlName="locationCity" maxlength="60">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="license_number">License Number: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="licenseNumber" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseNumber" maxlength="256">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location_state">Location State: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="locationState" formControlName="locationState" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeState($event.target.value);getStateText($event)">
                  <option value="">Please select</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let state of statesList" [value]="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <span class="errorMsg">{{geoError}}</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="issuing_authority">Issuing Authority Name: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="issuingAuthorityName" class="form-control" formControlName="issuingAuthorityName" maxlength="256">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location_country">Location Country: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="locationCountry" formControlName="locationCountry" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value);getCountryText($event)">
                  <option *ngFor ="let country of countriesList" [value]="country.id">{{country.name ? country.name : country.isoName}} </option>
              </select>
              <span class="errorMsg">{{geoError}}</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group search_btn">
      <!-- <button [disabled]="!licenseOwner && !locationCity && !locationAddress && !dbaName && !licenseNumber && !stateSelected && !issuingAuthority" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> -->
      <button [disabled]="advSearchForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

But the above is not working. What wrong I am doing here? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: It seems correct. Can you send us more code?

Comment: updated the question with more required code

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console when you change value of formcontrols?

Comment: Yes, getting ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'DBAName' for all controls under noCountry group

Comment: Can you share your html code as well?

Comment: Added HTML as well

Answer (score 1):

you should change in HTML code, wrap all formControl which is under noCountry formGroup.

like:

```
<div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">License Owner: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="licenseOwnerName" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseOwnerName" maxlength="256">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="advSearchForm" class="search_main_form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">License Owner: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="licenseOwnerName" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseOwnerName" maxlength="256">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Location Address Line 1: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="locationAddressLine1" class="form-control" formControlName="locationAddressLine1" maxlength="256">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dba_name">DBA Name: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="DBAName" class="form-control" formControlName="DBAName" maxlength="255">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location_city">Location City: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="locationCity" class="form-control" formControlName="locationCity" maxlength="60">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="license_number">License Number: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="licenseNumber" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseNumber" maxlength="256">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location_state">Location State: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="locationState" formControlName="locationState" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeState($event.target.value);getStateText($event)">
                  <option value="">Please select</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let state of statesList" [value]="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
                </select>
                    <span class="errorMsg">{{geoError}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col" formGroupName="noCountry">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="issuing_authority">Issuing Authority Name: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="issuingAuthorityName" class="form-control" formControlName="issuingAuthorityName" maxlength="256">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="location_country">Location Country: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="locationCountry" formControlName="locationCountry" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value);getCountryText($event)">
                  <option *ngFor ="let country of countriesList" [value]="country.id">{{country.name ? country.name : country.isoName}} </option>
              </select>
                    <span class="errorMsg">{{geoError}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group search_btn">
        <!-- <button [disabled]="!licenseOwner && !locationCity && !locationAddress && !dbaName && !licenseNumber && !stateSelected && !issuingAuthority" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> -->
        <button [disabled]="advSearchForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

through the above changes, your HTML side error solve.